# express-cassandra update function gives an "invalid amount of bind variables"

Tags: cassandra, express-cassandra

I have the following update service:

```
const editMessage = async (channelId, messageId, message) => {
    const searchByQuery = {
        id: models.timeuuidFromString(messageId),
        channelId: models.uuidFromString(channelId)
    }
    const updateQuery = {
        message,
        edited:true,
    }
    const updateAsync = util.promisify(models.instance.MessageStore.update).bind(models.instance.MessageStore);

    const updatedMessage = await updateAsync(searchByQuery,updateQuery)
    return updatedMessage;
}
```

However, whenever I try to run this, I get the following error:
`apollo.model.update.dberror: Error during update query on DB -> ResponseError: Invalid amount of bind variables`
On checking the query it runs the following one:   `query: 'UPDATE "message_store" SET "message"=?, "edited"=?, "updated_at"=toTimestamp(now()), "__v"=now() WHERE "id" = ? AND "channelId" = ?;'`
I am unable to check which variable is missing, since in the express-cassandra query, I am providing all the requisite ones.

I have tried changing variables to be updated, also have changed the number of vars to be updated, still no use. I have also changed the types before updating ex making id to string purposefully so and cassandra detects wrong data type but vars are kept shown missing.